# Busqueda de un dato de una columna y mostrar linea - android studio google sheet

Tags: java

tengo una aplicacion de android studio con conexion a google sheet en la cual puedo consultar los datos completos de la tabla y agregar datos nuevos, necesitaría saber como tengo que hacer para buscar un dato especifico de una columna y mostrar la linea completa,

es decir, en un edittext introducir un dato por.ej nombre y que filtre todos los nombres y pueda seleccionarlo para mostrar la linea completa de la tabla, y si se puede además editarlo pues mucho mejor.